# Setting `returnKeyType` of UITextField/UITextView to show ↵

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uitextview

I'm probably missing something stupid, but I can't find a way to change the return key of UITextFields/UITextViews to show ↵ (as in iMessage/Mail).

All options of `returnKeyType` seems to change the *text* shown in the return key.
(I think there must be a duplicate question of this, but I tried every possible combination of keywords to search for the solution.)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make return key to continue

[image: Continue Key From Storyboard]

And it will show `Continue` on some language and will show `↵` in some language.

[image: English Keyboard]

[image: Bengali Keyboard]

Comment: Then is it impossible to apply this to all languages?

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: Did you able to keep it on all the keyboard in  iMessage/Mail?

Comment: No, I didn't. But I was wondering if I could do this for all languages, since this was in a guideline of the project I was working on. Thank you, anyways.